# How to exclude {{{ ... }}} in flyspell-mode and flyspell-buffer?

Tags: emacs, aspell

I edit a lot of *MoinMoinWiki* pages in my emacs and love the `flyspell-mode`.
Preformatted stuff in `{{{...}}}` (in multiple lines) as well as "backtick *text* backtick" usually contains snippets of programming code which make no sense to spellcheck.

Can I configure `ispell`/`flyspell` not to include the programming code?

Example:

```
Bla bla lorem ipsum die Standardcontainer wie `vector` eine
''Methode'' haben, die ein einzelnes Argument nimmt, also
`vector<T>::swap(vector<T)>&)`. Bla bla und diese `swap`-Methoden sind
von dieser Sorte. Warum das so ist, sehen wir gleich. Bla bla
was '''kanonisch''' ist bla bla Template-Funktion<<tlitref(stdswap)>>

{{{#!highlight c++ title="Man könnte 'std::swap@LT@@GT@' spezialisieren"
namespace std {
  template<> // wir können durchaus im namespace std spezialisieren
  void swap<Thing>(Thing&, Thing&) {
    // ...hier swappen...
  }
}
}}}

Nun, das würde sicherlich in diesem Fall helfen, doch es bleibt ein
größeres Problem: Eine teilweise Spezialisierung lorem ipsum bla bla
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The variable `ispell-skip-region-alist` does what you want when spell checking the buffer, but not for flyspell.  Just add an entry like

```
(add-to-list 'ispell-skip-region-alist
             '("^{{{" . "^}}}"))
```

Unfortunately, it's not as easy to get flyspell to ignore certain regions.  You have to use `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate` which is a function.  Several modes already define this so you would have to add the following as advice to those functions.  I'll assume for simplicity though that you are using a mode (I used `text-mode` below) which doesn't have it defined.  Then you can add the following to your .emacs:

```
(defun flyspell-ignore-verbatim ()
  "Function used for `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate' to ignore {{{ }}} blocks."
  (save-excursion
    (widen)
    (let ((p (point))
          (count 0))
      (not (or (and (re-search-backward "^{{{" nil t)
                    (> p (point))
                    ;; If there is no closing }}} then assume we're still in it
                    (or (not (re-search-forward "^}}}" nil t))
                        (< p (point))))
               (eq 1 (progn (while (re-search-backward "`" (line-beginning-position) t)
                              (setq count (1+ count)))
                            (- count (* 2 (/ count 2))))))))))
(put 'text-mode 'flyspell-mode-predicate 'flyspell-ignore-verbatim)
```

Comment: perfect! My mode-line said `(Fundamental Fly)`. Hooking it to `flyspell-mode` did not work, but `fundamental-mode` instead of `text-mode` seems fine.

Comment: Hmm... how to I handle both: the `^{{{`...`^}}}` regex and the Backtick-word-Backtick one?

Comment: I added support for the backtick-text-backtick.  It assumes that such statements only appear on a single line—it counts whether there is an even or odd number of backticks on the line before it.

Comment: What should I do if the I want to ignore ispell inside `\href{ }`?

Comment: Basically, change the regular expressions from `^{{{` and `^}}}` to `\\href{` and `}`.  There will probably other differences, but fitting them in a comment would be difficult.  You would either add it as another statement in the `(or ...)` or remove the other expressions from the `(or ...)` depending on if you want to ignore those too.