# How to ignore jQuery selectors in flyspell?

Tags: emacs

I'm using `js2-mode` with `flyspell-prog-mode` to spellcheck comments and strings.

When using jQuery, you use selectors like `$("#something")` or `$('something else')`. Can I configure flyspell to not spellcheck these strings? Basically, anything wrapped in `$(` and `)`. Handling `jQuery(` and `)` would be cool, too, but I can probably manage that.

I found this question, which is similar, but I was unable to adapt it myself. [How to exclude {{{ ... }}} in flyspell-mode and flyspell-buffer?](https://superuser.com/questions/345084/how-to-exclude-in-flyspell-mode-and-flyspell-buffer)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short of it is you really can't, at least not without some serious hacking of flyspell and/or your major mode.

From the flyspell source

```
;;;###autoload
(defun flyspell-prog-mode ()
  "Turn on `flyspell-mode' for comments and strings."
  (interactive)
  (setq flyspell-generic-check-word-p 'flyspell-generic-progmode-verify)
  (flyspell-mode 1)
  (run-hooks 'flyspell-prog-mode-hook))
```

The relevant line being where we set the `flyspell-generic-check-word-p` function to `flyspell-generic-progmode-verify` that function looks like this

```
(defun flyspell-generic-progmode-verify ()
  "Used for `flyspell-generic-check-word-p' in programming modes."
  (let ((f (get-text-property (point) 'face)))
    (memq f flyspell-prog-text-faces)))
```

Finally we need to look at `flyspell-prog-text-faces`

```
(defvar flyspell-prog-text-faces
  '(font-lock-string-face font-lock-comment-face font-lock-doc-face)
  "Faces corresponding to text in programming-mode buffers.")
```

So as can now be readily seen, flyspell is using the fontface of the text to verify what it has been typed as ( this is actually probably the most efficient way for flyspell to handle this problem. It means that it doesn't have to re-parse your code ).

Your options are either a custom version of `flyspell-generic-progmode-verify` to load into `flyspell-generic-check-word-p` or modifying the major mode such that it produces different faces for your various strings.

Comment: These are not the only options. Before `(flyspell-prog-mode)` you can simply `(setq flyspell-prog-text-faces '(font-lock-comment-face font-lock-doc-face))` to disable strings. This works.